# Indent letter in moderncv casual style

Tags: indentation, moderncv, letters

I'm trying to indent the first line of each paragraph in the cover letter of the `moderncv` template. So far I added this at the beginning of the .tex to justify it, but I haven't found a way to indent.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}% <cmd>
    {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
    {\@opening}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Can I add anything in there to indent? Or should I do something else?

-- Edit --

This is the letter part in the code

```
 \clearpage

 \recipient{Empresa contratante}{A coruña, España} % Letter recipient
 \date{\today} % Letter date
 \opening{Estimados Srs,} % Opening greeting
 \closing{Atentamente,} % Closing phrase
 \enclosure[Adjunto]{Curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

 \makelettertitle % Print letter title

 This is the part where I write my letter and I want it to be indented

 \end{adjustwidth}

 \makeletterclosing % Print letter signature
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is interesting, but a minimal example of code is needed.

Comment: I added a little more code, I don't know if it was what you needed. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add also `\documentclass` and the other bits that make the example compilable?

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm a first timer in LaTex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already patching `\makelettertitle`, you can add the settings there:

```
\makeatletter
% patch \makelettertitle to use justification and normal indentation
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}% <cmd>
  {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\parindent=11pt % or what you think best
   \parskip=0pt plus 0.1pt % remove the blank lines between paragraphs
   \@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

% patch \makeletterclosing to have the closing flush left
\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}
  {\@closing}
  {\vspace{1.5em}\noindent\@closing}% the same vertical space as at the start
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, it worked to perfection, thanks!! But I would prefer the closing to be in the left as the opening is... Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Álvaro You need to add `\noindent`; see the modified code.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer. Can't validate it because I don't have enough rep yet...

Answer (score 3):

For `moderncv` documents, I usually use this hack to force indentation, placing it at the beginning of part I want to have indentation in:

```
\leftskip 0.1in
\parindent -0.2in
```

And then to change back to normal, this at the end of the section:

```
\leftskip 0in
\parindent 0in
```

Answer (score 2):

I just add `{\hskip 0.5em}` at the beginning of each paragraph. Maybe not systematic as the other answers, but this works fine for me.